# FeatureUnion: keep existing features plus add new engineered features (aka transformed columns)

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, feature-engineering

Say I have a dataset with 2 numerical columns and I would like to add a third column which is the product of the two (or some other function of the two existing columns). I can compute the new feature using a `ColumnTransformer`:

```
tfs = make_column_transformer(
  (FunctionTransformer(lambda X: np.sqrt(X[:,0] - X[:,1]).reshape(-1, 1)), ["colX", "colY"]),
)
```

(`X` is a pandas `DataFrame`, therefore the indexing via column names. Note also the  `reshape` I had to use. Maybe someone has a better idea there.)

As written above I would like to keep the original features (similar to what `sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures` is doing), i.e. use all 3 columns to fit a linear model (or generally use them in an `sklearn` pipeline). How do I do this?

For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'colX': [3, 4], 'colY': [2, 1]}) 
tfs = make_column_transformer(
  (FunctionTransformer(lambda X: np.sqrt(X[:,0] - X[:,1]).reshape(-1, 1)), ["colX", "colY"]),
)
tfs.fit_transform(df)
```

gives

```
array([[1.        ],
      [1.73205081]])
```

but I would like to get an array that includes the original columns to pass this on in the `pipeline`.

The only way I could think of is a `FeatureUnion` with an identity transformation for the first two columns. Is there a more direct way?

(I would like to make a pipeline rather than change the `DataFrame` so that I do not forget to make the augmentation when calling `model.predict()`.)

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.make_column_transformer.html) more carefully I found that it is possible to pass "special-cased strings" to "indicate to drop the columns or to pass them through untransformed, respectively."

So one possibility to achieve my goal is

```
tfs = make_column_transformer(
  (FunctionTransformer(lambda X: np.sqrt(X[:,0] - X[:,1]).reshape(-1, 1)), ["colX", "colY"]),
  ("passthrough", df.columns)
)
```

yielding

```
array([[1.        , 3.        , 2.        ],
       [1.73205081, 4.        , 1.        ]])
```

In the end there is thus no need for `FeatureUnion` but it can be done with `ColumnTransformer` or `make_column_transformer` alone, resp.